# How to REPLACE a MySql value from 0 to 1 for specific entries

Tags: mysql, replace, database-schema

I want to update or replace (whichever works better/safer) a table in my MySql database.

The table is called `*editornofollow*`

and it contains `3 columns:`

```
 1. Some unique numerical IDs (I have around 10000 Ids from which only
    like 3000 need to be updated) 
 2. edchoice (no need to replace anythinghere) 
 3. nofollow (here are values of 0 or 1 - if it's 0 means that the ID attributed to a specific link is dofollowed by search engines, if it's 1 - it's nofollowed).
```

And what I want is to replace like 3000 of those ZEROS into 1's.

The command should be something like:

replace `if id {id1, id2, id3, id4, id4, id6 etc}` column dofollowed with value `1.`

Can someone who knows Mysql better help me?

I had the command in some file, was done by someone years ago, but... obviously I cant find the file. I just know it was a long command, since it contained all those numerical IDs.

Comment: share table structure and some sample data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you question correctly this should work:

```
UPDATE editornofollow
SET nofollow = 1
WHERE id IN (id1,id2,id3)
```

You update table editornofollow, you set the nofollow column to 1 for all rows where the id column can be found in the array (id1,id2,id3)

Comment: Thanks, I,ll try this out, hope it works. Will be back with the outcome of it. ;)

Comment: sure thing :) maybe make a copy of the database just in case! never try on live data

Answer (score 0):

if you need to select those ids instead of writing them , and 2nd if you want to writes all these ids.
any of them will work :)

```
UPDATE editornofollow 
       SET nofollow = '0'
     WHERE id IN (select ID from ...) //
    or
    UPDATE editornofollow 
       SET nofollow = '0'
     WHERE id IN (id1,id2,id3 ....) //
```

Comment: Hi guys and thanks a ton for your help. I'd mark your answers as useful but I can't use the "this answer was useful" feature since I dont have 15 rep points yet.

The correct SQL query was:

UPDATE editornofollow
SET nofollow = 1
WHERE id IN (id1,id2,id3);